# I created a HTTP proxy using Google Cloud Functions but the response isn't the same?

Tags: node.js, axios, google-cloud-functions, http-proxy

I have set up a Google Cloud Function using node.js and I want it to forward the request to an endpoint and have it return the same response as the endpoint. The response should be a JPEG image however I am getting a different response to what it should be.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "forward-request",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "description": "A Google Cloud Function that forwards requests to another URL.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.22.0"
  }
}
```

My index.js:

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.forwardRequest = async (req, res) => {
  const targetUrl = `https://media.rightmove.co.uk`;

  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: req.method,
      url: targetUrl + req.url,
      headers: {
        ...req.headers,
        host: `media.rightmove.co.uk`
      },
      data: req.body
    });
    res.set('etag', response.headers.etag);
    res.set('content-type', response.headers['content-type']);
    res.status(response.status);
    res.send(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('An error occurred while proxying the request.');
  }
};
```

When I navigate to the cloud function URL in the browser ".../hero_image.jpg", the response I get is not the same as this URL: https://media.rightmove.co.uk/hero_image.jpg

This is the cloud function URL: https://europe-west2-fit-discipline-129416.cloudfunctions.net/sturents-property-images/hero_image.jpg

(note I'm using the rightmove URL here as an example, as it replicates the same issue, this isn't the same endpoint that I will be using for production)

Sometimes in the response I get "An error occurred while proxying the request." error and this is the error message: Error: Request failed with status code 411

Comment: What is the exact value of `req.url` that we see in `url: targetUrl + req.url`?

Comment: req.url is /hero_image.jpg

so targetUrl + req.url is https://media.rightmove.co.uk/hero_image.jpg

Comment: Are you sure?  `url` isn't a property of an Express Request object. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req I suggest doing some debugging here.

Comment: I output the value of req.url in the console and it returned /hero_image.jpg

I am not using express, it isn't referenced in my package.json

Comment: The res and req objects are actually Express compatible objects. See the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions): "*Your HTTP handler function must be an Express middleware function that accepts the request and response arguments and sends an HTTP response.*"

Comment: Thanks for the information, fair enough but the value of `req.url` is definitely `/hero_image.jpg` as I output that to the console.

Comment: It may be due to temporary network failures or the target URL being unavailable. In such cases, you could implement a retry logic with a backoff mechanism to handle these issues.